# How can i authenticate my Quickbook Intuit api access without user interection and just by client id and secret?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am working on a project where backgroung crons create invoices and i want to add them on my quickbook account on create on backend, so problem is i want to hit api with just client id and secret involvement.

Answer (score 4):

> How can i authenticate my Quickbook Intuit api access without user interection and just by client id and secret?

You can't. *But you don't need to either*. You misunderstand how OAuth v2 works when using `refresh token` type grants.

The way OAuth v2 with `refresh token` grants works is like this --

- The developer goes through a *one-time* UI process to get the `client ID` and `client secret`, and define callback URLs - https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#download-the-oauth-library
- The person who owns the `QuickBooks Online` account goes through a *one-time* and *only one-time* UI-based connection process which exchanges the `client ID` and `client secret` for an `authorization code`, and then that for an `access token` and `refresh token` - https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-1-prepare-authorization-request
- Your code *stores* the OAuth `access` and `refresh tokens`.

Now, you can run your `cron` job whenever you want, *using the stored `access` and `refresh tokens`*.

At some point, you will get back a `401` response from Intuit - this means your `access token` has expired (it is only valid for 1 hour). When this happens:

- Make an API call to refresh the `access token` - https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#refresh-the-token
- *Store* the new `access token` *and the new `refresh token`* (you may or may not get back a new refresh token, so you should just store what you get back every time regardless)
- Make your API call again, and it will succeed

Repeat in your cron process whenever you want, as desired.

To re-iterate - the UI-based auth process is *one-time* and *one-time ONLY*. After that *one-time* process you store the tokens and can make calls from your background/cron processes whenever you need to.

Comment: And the easiest way to go through getting the first set of access and refresh tokens is to use the playground. You then have 1 hour to put those tokens into the app and start refreshing when required.

Comment: This ^^^ is absolutely a great way to get started. Be aware that if you want to be listed on Intuit's App store (https://apps.intuit.com/app/apps/home) you will eventually need to actually implement the whole OAuth process. But for initial testing or one-off/in-house projects, the Playground ( https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#oauth-2-0-playground ) is great!

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. This works fine for refreshing the access token etc, but I keep getting 400 errors when accessing eg company info. In the docs it mentions you need to supply the realmID when refreshing a token, could that be the issue? That I effectively have a valid token but it's not linked to any company that I can access?

Comment: @OliverMason Impossible to say without seeing what you're sending, and what you're getting back. I would recommend you start another question since that sounds unrelated to the original question here.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. appreciate the explicit answer, but it's an overly complex solution to a problem that shouldn't exist. All of this could and should be replaced with a simple client_id and client_secret pointing at your own quickbooks account.   One-time kickoffs, expiring tokens, extra infrastructure, extra models, extra cronjobs.... All to patch an access pattern oAuth is not designed for.  OAuth is the right solution when other businesses connect, and authentication is in the user loop. But this is not that. Two access patterns should exist, not forcing one to jump through hoops.

Comment: @Roman I don't work for Intuit, so I can't really help with that. You should reach out to Intuit and ask them for that functionality. For what it's worth - I agree it'd be nice to not have to build the OAuth connection pieces for single-QuickBooks-account apps... but right now, Intuit does not allow that.