# Authentication issue with Intuit Quickbooks API - .NET

Tags: .net, intuit-partner-platform

I am creating a Windows Service and API for a client using .net 4.7.2.  My goal is to have the service ingest my API and connect that API to Intuit's Quickbooks API to retrieve the client's invoice and payment details.
I've been following the examples provided by Intuit but it requires a user to enter their intuit credentials before calling the callback url.  Since this is an API there will not be a user monitoring the application to enter user credentials.
Is there a way to get the intuit's API authentication details (code and realmId) without user interaction (logging in)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i authenticate my Quickbook Intuit api access without user interection and just by client id and secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577398/how-can-i-authenticate-my-quickbook-intuit-api-access-without-user-interection-a)