# Quickbooks php curl authenticated GET request fails

Tags: php, http, curl, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have set up a company in the QuickBooks developer portal, and have successfully created an OAuth token (which I can refresh [as specified in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582368/127839)). So, unlike the majority of these questions, this is *not* about OAuth... I'm using bare PHP here, as I cannot use the SDK for technical reasons.

After getting the OAuth token, I am trying to perform the next API call from the API playground, getting the company information. I effectively call the QB API with this code:

(`$query` is `/v3/company/<companyID>/companyinfo/<companyID>` (companyID is the "Realm ID" from the API playground), `$base` is the sandbox-URL (same as "Sandbox Base URL" in the header), `$access_tokens["access"]` is the OAuth access token; `$url` is `https://${base}${query}`)

```
$headers = array(
    "GET " . $query . " HTTP/2",
    "Host: " . $base,
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_tokens["access"],
    "Production Base URL: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com",
    "Sandbox Base URL: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
```

After the call, the value of `$output` is:

```
HTTP/2 400 
date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 14:42:55 GMT
content-type: text/plain
content-length: 11
server: envoy

Bad Request
```

The request headers (as returned by the QB server via `curl_getinfo`) are:

```
GET /v3/company/4...0/companyinfo/4...0 HTTP/2
Host: sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
accept: application/json
authorization: Bearer e...Q
production base url: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com
sandbox base url: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
```

(the auth token and company ID have been cut)

If I call the URL directly in a browser, I get a 401 (authentication error) as expected, so I assume the OAuth part works (as I said, I can successfully retrieve an access token and refresh it). I'm just wondering if there is anything else that I'm doing wrong which causes the QB API call to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot here that looks a little funky... I would start by trying these things:

- Removing the invalid `GET` header. `GET` is not a valid HTTP header (it's part of the method/verb instead), and you shouldn't be trying to specify `HTTP/2` in this way. Remove this:

```
"GET " . $query . " HTTP/2",
```

- Remove the two other invalid HTTP headers. It looks like you're confusing Intuit's documentation for HTTP headers here. These are not valid headers and you should not be sending them:

```
"Production Base URL: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com",
"Sandbox Base URL: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
```

- Don't specify the `Host:` header to cURL. There's no reason to, and it could potentially conflict with the URL you pass cURL. cURL will calculate and send this for you.

```
"Host: " . $base,
```

I'd also check tomake sure you're sending the request to the correct URL. If it's for a sandbox company, it goes to the sandbox URL. If it's for a production company, it goes to the production URL.

Comment: Thank you, that was it -- it works with the changes you mention!